# Deployment Manager - autogen has resource level errors

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have been trying, for a couple a days, to deploy WHM - Cpanel, with vary configs etc.. including auto and manual VPC Network.

Here is the display of error/s.

vmp-cpanel-manual has resource level errors
vmp-cpanel-manual-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"412","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":412,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"If-Match","locationType":"header","message":"Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 338012702934. Add instance projects/vmg-project-35636/zones/australia-southeast1-a/instances/vmp-cpanel-manual-vm to the constraint to use external IP with it.","reason":"conditionNotMet"}],"message":"Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 338012702934. Add instance projects/vmg-project-35636/zones/australia-southeast1-a/instances/vmp-cpanel-manual-vm to the constraint to use external IP with it.","statusMessage":"Precondition Failed","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vmg-project-35636/zones/australia-southeast1-a/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

This is the first one I have done. I really want this to work, any clues on this, greatly appreciated.